# What species is this? What the fruit?

Tags: species-identification, botany, fruit

[image]

[image]

The berries of the fruit are sweet. The tree is growing in Israel.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/86277/edit) your post to include where this tree was growing  — for identification questions it is important (and often essential) that you include location information.  Pictures of the bark could also be helpful.

Comment: @tyersome I added bark

Comment: This does look somewhat similar to a mulberry though I agree it doesn't look right for a white mulberry.  I would, however, guess that it is something in the [Moraceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moraceae) (Mulberry family). —— To test this you could break a small branch or tear a leaf — plants in this family produce latex (a milky looking sap) when damaged.

Comment: @tyersome after thinking about this, I agree.

Comment: Is this a street/landscape tree?  What town?  Jerusalem has a detailed tree [inventory](http://greenmap.org.il/content?lang=en&pageid=51) if you read Hebrew.

Comment: @Bryan Hanson yes it is street (planted) tree in a park. It is in Haifa.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't locate a street tree inventory for Haifa.  And street trees are frequently not native, which expands the range of possibilities. Your pictures are great, someone will surely know this tree but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @tyersome I tested for white sap and there was none.

Comment: Well that's confusing!  Maybe Haifa has an urban forestry department (or something similar) that might have someone who can answer this?  If you do get an answer, please share it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is *Phytolacca dioica*.  I found this by searching your first image in a phone app called Pl@ntNet (PlantNet).  Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytolacca_dioica) confirms the ID.

Interestingly, you said the fruit was sweet.  The North American relative *Phytolacca americana* is extremely poisonous.  A brief search suggests your species is possibly poisonous, with reports about the leaves more common than the fruit.

Comment: This site says the berries are juicy so can reduce thristyness: http://travelermap.ru/chudesa-prirody-13/

Comment: Good to know!  Another interesting difference is that your specimen's berries are yellow-green, while *P. americana* has intensely red-purple berries, due to betalain pigments.  Glad we figured this one out!

Comment: Phytolacca esculenta also has black berries but it is edible and cultivated. The difference between this and american variety is the form of the berries. Also, dioica is a tree while the other two are not.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps a white mulberry? See the Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morus_alba

Comment: Of course, not. The berries are of totally different size and the leaves are totally different.